# Bash: How to paste a script and have the CLI write it to disk

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to use a VM that is not connected to the internet. I can, however, paste it a shell script to execute.

How can I transform this code (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sajitsasi/az-ip-fwd/main/ip_fwd.sh) into a shell script that will be written to disk. I cannot `curl` since I have no internet access. I can however pass in the code.

I have tried:

`long pasted code here` > `testfile.sh`

Comment: Use a [Here document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Here_strings).

Comment: A simple thing to try is `cat > testfile.sh` in a shell window, then paste the code into the same window while it has the focus.  Finally type <enter> and then <ctl-D>.  Unless the script is _extremely_ long (like more than several megabytes), this ought to work. I've done it many times.

Comment: `cat > testfile.sh`, etc did exactly what was needed!

Comment: What does _paste it a shell script_ mean?  What is the meaning of _a shell script that will be written to disk_? Usually, shell scripts are stored on a disk, because you are using a text editor to create them.